# Facing problem building flutter app. How to solve this issue?

Tags: flutter, dart, ubuntu, cmake

How to identify which package is required and how can I solve this issue

I want to build my first flutter app in ubuntu 22.04LTS. And this problem is app isn't building:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:603 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:825 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  flutter/CMakeLists.txt:25 (pkg_check_modules)
```

[image: building error]

Comment: try this one `flutter clean && flutter pub`

Comment: after applying this command it's also shows the same error message

Comment: share complete log `flutter run -v` using this command

Comment: Please read [ask] and write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are missing this one. run this command and then `flutter clean && flutter pub && flutter run`

```
sudo apt install curl file git unzip xz-utils zip libglu1-mesa clang cmake \ 
ninja-build pkg-config libgtk-3-dev
```

if you still facing issue you have to folow these steps [here](https://www.how2shout.com/linux/2-ways-to-install-flutter-on-ubuntu-20-04-18-04-21-04-linux/) to reinstall flutter on `Ubuntu` `20.04 |18.04 | 21.04` `Linux`